# installing multiple gcc on centOS 7

Tags: linux, gcc, centos, wget, yum

I'm new to centOS and whole yum and repo system, and I'm trying to install multiple gcc on my centOS 7.

As far as I understand, yum tries to get the necessery files from the given repositories. I used this answer to get started:

https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos

Yet soon, when I tried installing the gcc, it gives me this error:

> # failure: repodata/repomd.xml from testing-devtools-2-centos-7: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try
>   http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/7/x86_64/RPMS/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found

After that I tried installing devtools-1.1 but it gave me this error:

> Error getting repository data for testing-1.1-devtools-6, repository not found

I shortly came to the conclusion that I'm not entirely aware of how centOS works. Can anyone help me understanding the situation and getting gcc installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be because no such devtools repository exists.

Presumably because CentOS 7 has only existed officially since yesterday and because it ships with gcc 4.8.2 already.

Comment: So does that mean I should wait for the repos, or should I try installing it manually? Although I used the centOS iso labeled "Everything" I can't find any gcc installed. But it's still possibly that I did something wrong.

Comment: @user3655785 Have you tried running `yum install gcc` and seeing what happens?

Comment: I just tried it. It gave the same error. It managed to do the files `base` and `extras` but after that it can't find any working mirror.

Comment: I just had to learn to hard way that repos generate their own links using information of the system. So you were right, there are no repositories for centOS 7 yet. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Normal CentOS 7 repositories exist, no devtools repository for CentOS 7 exists.